# How to extract index from a button in Listview?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have an unusual question. How to extract index from a button in Listview. 
I would like `<Button Clicked = "indexOne" Text = "{Binding Answers [0]}" />` to have index 0 e.t.c
Sorry for my english.

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <ListView x:Name="elo"   Margin="10,0" RowHeight="250">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell >
                        <Grid >
                            <StackLayout >
                                <Label Text="{Binding Question1}"   />
                                <Button Clicked="indexOne" Text="{Binding Answers[0]}" />
                                <Button Clicked="indexTwo"  Text="{Binding Answers[1]}" />
                                <Button Clicked="indexThree" Text="{Binding Answers[2]}"/>
                                <Button Clicked="indexFour" Text="{Binding Answers[3]}" />

                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: if you have different clicked handlers for each button then you can just hardcode the index.

Comment: I have a problem with that. How to encode the index? Do you have any advice?

Comment: In each button you can use a command and set the command parameter to the index you want to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO !

You can use the [Xamarin.Forms MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to achiece that , not sure this is the best way to achieve that . If later have good solutions will update here .

Here is the sample code to explain that .Create a **OptionClass** to store Option of Question .

```
public class OptionClass 
{
    // add QuestionID
    public int QuestionID { set; get; }

    public string OptionTitle { set; get; }

    public int OptionIndex { set; get; }

    // add int[] for button command paramater 
    public int[] IDValues {
        get
        {
            return new int[] { QuestionID, OptionIndex };
        } 
    }
    public ICommand OptionChooseCommand { set; get; }

}
```

Create a **QuestionClass**  class to generate each question data :

```
public class QuestionClass 
{
    public string  QuestionTitle { set; get; }

    // add QuestionID
    public int  QuestionID { set; get; }

    public List<OptionClass> optionClasses { set; get; }

    public QuestionClass(string title,List<OptionClass> options, int questionId)
    {
        optionClasses = new List<OptionClass>();
        QuestionTitle = title;
        optionClasses = options;
        QuestionID = questionId;
    }
}
```

Last , creat a **AnsweViewModel** to generate list data of questions :

```
public class AnsweViewModel 
{
    private MainPage mainPage;

    public List<QuestionClass> questionClasses { set; get; }

    public AnsweViewModel(MainPage mainPage)
    {
        this.mainPage = mainPage;
        questionClasses = new List<QuestionClass>();

        List<OptionClass> optionsOne = new List<OptionClass>();
        optionsOne.Add(new OptionClass()
        {
            QuestionID = 0,
            OptionTitle = "A",
            OptionIndex = 1,
            OptionChooseCommand = new Command<int[]>((int[] value) => {
                MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int[]>(mainPage, "ButtonInfo", value);
            })
        });
        optionsOne.Add(new OptionClass()
        {
            QuestionID = 0,
            OptionTitle = "B", OptionIndex = 2,
            OptionChooseCommand = new Command<int[]>((int[] value) => {
                MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int[]>(mainPage, "ButtonInfo", value);
            })
        });
        optionsOne.Add(new OptionClass() {
            QuestionID = 0,
            OptionTitle = "C", OptionIndex = 3,
            OptionChooseCommand = new Command<int[]>((int[] value) => {
                MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int[]>(mainPage, "ButtonInfo", value);
            })
        });
        optionsOne.Add(new OptionClass()
        {
            QuestionID = 0,
            OptionTitle = "D", OptionIndex = 4,
            OptionChooseCommand = new Command<int[]>((int[] value) => {
                MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int[]>(mainPage, "ButtonInfo", value);
            })
        });

        questionClasses.Add(new QuestionClass("Question One", optionsOne, 0) { });

        List<OptionClass> optionsTwo = new List<OptionClass>();
        optionsTwo.Add(new OptionClass()
        {
            QuestionID = 1,
            OptionTitle = "A",
            OptionIndex = 1,
            OptionChooseCommand = new Command<int[]>((int[] value) => {
                MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int[]>(mainPage, "ButtonInfo", value);
            })
        });
        optionsTwo.Add(new OptionClass()
        {
            QuestionID = 1,
            OptionTitle = "B",
            OptionIndex = 2,
            OptionChooseCommand = new Command<int[]>((int[] value) => {
                MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int[]>(mainPage, "ButtonInfo", value);
            })
        });
        optionsTwo.Add(new OptionClass()
        {
            QuestionID = 1,
            OptionTitle = "C",
            OptionIndex = 3,
            OptionChooseCommand = new Command<int[]>((int[] value) => {
                MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, int[]>(mainPage, "ButtonInfo", value);
            })
        });
        questionClasses.Add(new QuestionClass("Question Two", optionsTwo, 1) { });
    }
}
```

Here in **Xaml** , use **[Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts)** to show option view . If always options are four items, not need to use this .

```
<ListView x:Name="elo"
            Margin="10,0"
            RowHeight="250">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding QuestionTitle}" />
                        <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding optionClasses}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Text="{Binding OptionTitle}"
                                            Command="{Binding OptionChooseCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding IDValues}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In **ContentPage** , code as follow :

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AnsweViewModel answeViewModel = new AnsweViewModel(this);
        elo.ItemsSource = answeViewModel.questionClasses;

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage,int>(this, "ButtonIndex", (sender,arg) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Question is " + answeViewModel.questionClasses[arg[0]].QuestionTitle + " Button Index is : " + arg[1]);
            DisplayAlert("Question is " + answeViewModel.questionClasses[arg[0]].QuestionTitle, " Button Index is : " + arg[1], "Ok");
            // Do something whenever the "Hi" message is received
        });
    }
}
```

The **updated** effect :(not need to care about which cell be selected )

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very cool solution. I'm using api and I've found that I will compare the button text with the correct answer from the api. However, I have such a problem that when I display a few answers on the page sometimes bites and shows me the correct answer in another question. Can this be remedied?

Comment: @ReVoPEP Add a `QuestionID` inside model , then when clicking will know which index of cell be . I will update answer , you can have a look at that when you have time .